# Python BeautifulSoup Spider is not working

Tags: python, web-crawler

Hi I'm trying to learn how to scrap elements with python, and I was trying to get the title of a web page (local.ch) but my code is not working and I don't know why.

here the python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 2
    while page < max_pages:
        url = 'http://yellow.local.ch/fr/q/Morges/Bar.html?page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'details-entry-title-link'}):
            title = link.string
            print(title)
        page += 1

spider(3)
```

I'm pretty sure that the code is correct I don't have any error on pycharm, why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a major bug in your code:

```
page = 1
while page < max_pages
....
spider(1)
```

The condition is never met, and the  rest of your code doesn't get executed!
Some other bugs are encoding error and unspecified parser warnings:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://yellow.local.ch/fr/q/Morges/Bar.html?page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text.encode("utf-8")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'details-entry-title-link'}):
            title = link.string
            print(title.encode("utf-8"))
        page += 1

spider(1)
```

Note the encoding `"utf-8"` part - this encoding will result in binary output, as you can see from the `b` prefix. Without this step, the `print()` function will throw an error. The same change is made on `plain_textplain_text = source_code.text.encode("utf-8")` line.

Another bug is the wrong indentation of `page += 1` line. It should be inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because, you intended to initialize the page variable from 0 not 1. Presently, it never enters the loop.
Because, both page and max page do have same value which is 1.

Comment: hmm true, I have changed my code but it is still not working, I'll edit my changes

Comment: I just ran the code in my system. It gave me this:
Caravela
le Casino
Pause-Café SA
Le CUBE escalade et bar
Le P'tit-Pressoir
Atlantide Wellness Center SA
Wuthrich G. et N. SA
Chevrier & Caprara Sàrl

Is this not the output you required?

Comment: Okay I didn't run the good file that's why it did not work thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

To the function `spider` you are passing 1 as the `max_pages` argument. However, your while loop will only execute if `page < max_pages`. 1 < 1 is not true.